# Why is this action faithful? (Proof that the automorphism group of $A_n$ is $S_n$ for $n\geq 7$.)

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-actions

I'm currently trying to work through a proof that Aut$(A_n) \cong S_n$. In particular I'm looking at theorem 2.3 (on page 18) in R. Wilson's book 'The Finite Simple Groups'. (Click [here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDMQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9781848009875-c2.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-855487-p173841638&ei=zssWVKXHC6WJ7AbclIGwAQ&usg=AFQjCNFOG2yW2b6aaOPkqK9wVcAlfokm8w&sig2=QpjMwesdISWOhkTKlnpLSg) for a download link provided by Springer.)

If I've understood the proof correctly, it works by showing that Aut$(A_n)$ acts as $S_n$ on the set of the $n$ point-stabilisers in $A_n$. So there exists a surjective homomorphism Aut$(A_n) \rightarrow S_n$.

My question is why is this homomorphism injective, i.e. why is the above action faithful? Stated another way, why is an automorphism of $A_n$ which fixes all of the point-stabilisers the trivial automorphism?

Comment: Which page number are you referring to in the book/link?  Also, I'm curious which book this is.

Comment: @AshwinGanesan I've updated my question to answer yours

Comment: One can extend that argument in the last paragraph before the theorem to show that if $\rho$ sends all $A_{n-1}$ to itself, then $\rho$ fixes all $3$-cycles.

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang. Something like this?: Under $\rho$ all 3-cycles must map to 3-cycles. 
(Let $x\in A_n$ be a 3-cycle. $\rho(x)$ centralises a subgroup $H$ of $A_n$ isomorphic to $A_{n-3}$,
which must have an orbit of at least $n-3$ points.)
$x$ and $\rho(x)$ must cycle the same 3 points since $\rho$ fixes the point stabilisers. So $\rho(x)=x$ or $\rho(x)=x^{-1}$. How can I show $\rho(x)\neq x^{-1}$?

Comment: Note that $\rho$ also fixes the $A_4$'s.

Comment: @QuangHoang I can see that $\rho$ does fix the groups of the form $\langle (abc), (abd) \rangle \cong A_4$. I can't see how this forces $\rho(x)\neq x^{-1}$ though.

Comment: If $(abc)\mapsto (cba)$, then what do $(abd)$ and $(bcd)$ map to? Note that $\rho(x)=x^{-1}$ for all $x$ is *not* a homomorphism.

Comment: By the argument in the paragraph you mentioned, $(abd)\mapsto (dba)$ and $(bcd)\mapsto (cbd)$. I can see that in fact all 3-cycles would be forced to map to their inverses. I know that inversion is not an automporphism for non-abelian groups, but I can't see why inversion on the set of 3-cycles can't induce an automomorphism on the whole of $A_n$.

Comment: @QuangHoang I believe that trying to define $\rho$ by inverting 3-cycles and extending to all of $A_n$ will lead to a contradiction, but I can't see what at the moment. Can you help?

Comment: @MattGallagher $(ab)(cd)=(abc)(bcd)=(abd)(bdc)$.

Comment: Ah I see. So if $(abc)\mapsto (cba)$ then the image of $(ab)(cd)$ cannot be well-defined. Thanks!